# SwiftUI: Link together with NavigationLink as list item

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

How can one have a list where each item in the list contains a `Link` and a `NavigationLink`?

When putting the `Link` and `NavigationLink` next to each other in an `HStack` both get triggered wherever I tap on the row.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Link(
                        "Link",
                        destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
                    )
                    NavigationLink(
                        "Other View",
                        destination: Text("Hello from other view"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the way Apple recommend to do this is to explicitly set the style on the `Link` button. e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Link(
                        "Link",
                        destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
                    )
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless) // <-- add this
                    NavigationLink(
                        "Other View",
                        destination: Text("Hello from other view"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer based on excellent notes over here [https://swiftui-lab.com/random-lessons/](https://www.swiftui-lab.com/random-lessons#list-3). Do wish Apple would improve their SwiftUI docs!

Previous, it worked, but don't really recommend way of doing it by adding `onTapGesture` to the `Link` that explicity opens the URL. left below for context.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @Environment(\.openURL) private  var openURL
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    
                    Link(
                        "Link",
                        destination: url!
                    )
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Opening URL \(url)")
                        openURL(url!)
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        "Other View",
                        destination: Text("Hello from other view")
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me in XCode 13 and iOS 15

Comment: This works if you replace the Link with a Text item

Answer (score 0):

Based on shufflingb's answer:

Replace the link with a non-tappable element and add a gesture handler to it.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.openURL) private  var openURL
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {

                    Text("Link")
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            openURL(url!)
                        }

                    NavigationLink(
                        "Other View",
                        destination: Text("Hello from other view")
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```